# Querying in rails - Double quoted string inside query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I need query like this

```
scope :find_email_usage, -> (id) {
    where("EXISTS ((with filter_table as (select id, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(filters) -> 'criteria') filter_json) select 1 from filter_table where filter_json @> '{\"mail_id\": ?}'))", id.to_s, id.to_s)

  }
```

But the structure has to be like `'{"a":1, "b":"2"}'::jsonb @> '{"b":2}'::jsonb`

How do I get the double quote in raw query using the substitution using ? in rails.

```
where("EXISTS ((with filter_table as (select id, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(filters) -> 'criteria') filter_json) select 1 from filter_table where filter_json @> '{\"mail_id\": "#{id.to_s}"))", id.to_s)
```

But any other ways to get the double quoted string inside raw query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to build a Ruby hash, convert that to JSON, and feed that string to the query:

```
where('EXISTS ((... where filter_json @> ?::jsonb))', { 'mail_id' => id.to_s }.to_json)
```